# Unraveling some JNI C++ code from the Android core

Tags: android, c++, java-native-interface

I'm not very experience in C++ and JNI so I have real trouble with some parts of this code (which is a part of the Android framework, more precisely comes from the CPP source of the `Surface` class):

```
static void Surface_unlockCanvasAndPost(
        JNIEnv* env, jobject clazz, jobject argCanvas)
{
    jobject canvas = env->GetObjectField(clazz, so.canvas);
    if (canvas != argCanvas) {
        doThrow(env, "java/lang/IllegalArgumentException", NULL);
        return;
    }

    const sp<Surface>& surface(getSurface(env, clazz));
    if (!Surface::isValid(surface))
        return;

    // detach the canvas from the surface
    SkCanvas* nativeCanvas =
        (SkCanvas*) env->GetIntField(canvas, no.native_canvas);
    int saveCount = env->GetIntField(clazz, so.saveCount);
    nativeCanvas->restoreToCount(saveCount);
    nativeCanvas->setBitmapDevice(SkBitmap());
    env->SetIntField(clazz, so.saveCount, 0);

    // unlock surface
    status_t err = surface->unlockAndPost();
    if (err < 0) {
        doThrow(env, "java/lang/IllegalArgumentException", NULL);
    }
}
```

What particularly bothers me is:

```
const sp<Surface>& surface(getSurface(env, clazz));
```

It's just puzzling me. There's no equals sign, and those templates are making it even harder to understand.

Could someone help me out with making out this particular line of code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is constructor call syntax for a reference - it's a bit obfuscatory to write it like this, like writing `int i(23);` instead of `int i = 23;`, but it is really equivalent to writing
`const sp<Surface>& surface = getSurface(env, clazz);`.

Comment: Gorgeous. Thanks a lot! Still, it really beats me as a syntax.

Comment: Well, it made sense for a language with value types, it is convenient to write `MyObject i("foo");` instead of `MyObject i = MyObject("foo");`.

Comment: do you know if this kind of notation has a name because it turns out it's everywhere in the core cpp files. It's really disturbing for a Java dev. Also, do you know if such syntax is valid in C?

Comment: @Albus: It's not valid C. It was introduced in C++ because it's the cleanest way to initialize value types that need constructor arguments. The syntax doesn't really have a special name, maybe constructor-call-syntax or something, it's pretty basic C++.